# how to upload zip files RAW to Nexus repository using api and python

Tags: python, api, maven, nexus

I need to upload some zip files to a repository, we are using Raw since they are just files that later on we will download and we are only keeping them for versioning

so i have a local zip file and a repository in nexus, how can i upload it using API,  do i need to create a folder in the repository first? or when i upload it the file i can specify the path and the API will create the folder structure in Nexus and put the zip file there?

i been trying to understand  but shows mavens and other software's

https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/rest-and-integration-api/assets-api

thanks guys.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find a good way to see how to pass the arguments, so i did it using the api
https://my_site.net/swagger-ui/#/components/uploadComponent
and then i copied the curl to https://curl.trillworks.com/#python and removed thing that were not needed, i ended up with,  hope works for some one on the future.

```
import requests
files = {
    'raw.directory': (None, 'testing/testing2'),  # folder structure you want in nexus
    'raw.asset1': (open('path/to/your/file.zip', 'rb')),
    'raw.asset1.filename': (None, 'desire_name.zip'),  # this is the name you want to see in nexus
}
response = requests.post('https://my_site/service/rest/v1/components?repository={repo_name}'.format(repo_name="your_repo"), files=files, auth=(NEXUS_USER, NEXUS_PASSWORD), verify=False)
```